# Why do some developers use constructor and super in their class in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, es6-class

I always use this expression in my components:

```
class Cart extends Component { }
```

Recently I have seen a lot of codes  using this expression.

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

Why is it? What is the purpose of using constructor and super? 
Is React.Component and Component same?
Why do we pass props in constructor and super?
I am not asking what super and constructor are, I am asking difference between 2 codes above and benefits of using each one?

I checked online but did not see any explanation, just code examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "super()" and "super(props)" in React when using es6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e)

Comment: Now with new es6 you don’t have to use constructor and super. However some people are used to old fashion way

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky not quite a duplicate, but the answer is functionally the same. The answer in the other thread should be referenced here.

Comment: Here's my opinion although I'm not a JS object model freak. `React.Component` and `Component` are the same reference i.e. the same thing, they just differ in usage based on how you import them in your code. If you import React only then you would have to use `React.Component` else you manually destructure `{ Component }` and then use it direct. You pass `props` to `super` because you are extending to `Component` which becomes your super class to which you are passing `props` to but `constructor` method itself is optional when you dont have any declarations in it.

Comment: So, you can also use functional component like: const MyComponent = (props) =>{...} it's more short and quickly

Answer (score 2):

Constructors and super are not react specific or even javascript specific. They are specific to the inheritance in **OOP**.

**Constructors**

Constructors are what can be called as initializing functions in a class. Let's look at an example where a constructor can be used.

```
class parentClass {
 constructor(){
   this.foo = foo;
   this.bar = bar;
}

function sharedMethod1(){
    print(this.foo);
}

function sharedMethod(){
    print(this.bar)
}
}

object1 = new ParentClass(foo1, bar1);

object1.sharedMethod1() // this will print foo1;
object1.sharedMethod2() // this will print bar1;

object2 = new ParentClass(foo2, bar2);
object2.sharedMethod1() // this will print foo2;
object2.sharedMethod2() // this will print bar2;
```

when there is a need to create multiple instances of a class with different values for member variables / functions, we make use of the constructor functions.

**Super**

The super keyword is used in inheritance as well. In inheritance when extending a child class from a parent class, there is a need to initialise the constructor of the parent class. The super keyword is used for this purpose. let's look at the below example for super.

```
class ParentClass (){
constructor(){
this.foo = foo;
}
} 

class childClass extends ParentClass(){
super(foo1); // super is used here initialize the constructor of the ParentClass
}
```

The same principle mentioned above is followed in React as well. 
Please look into dan abramov's blog post on constructor and super here https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/

Answer (score 1):

Dan Abramov [mentions on his blog](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/) that:

> You can’t use `this` in a constructor until after you’ve
>   called the parent constructor. 
>   JavaScript won’t let you.
>
> JavaScript enforces that if you want to use `this` in a constructor, you
>   have to call `super` first.

calling `super(props)` is needed in order to access `this.props`.

as mentioned [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022332/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-a-constructor-in-react), there are 2 main reasons to use a constructor on a react component:

> 1. Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
> 2. Binding
>      event handler methods to an instance.
>      If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t need to implement a constructor for your React component.
>
> **If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t
>   need to implement a constructor for your React component.**

Comment: That blog is for outdated es6. In new es7 there is no need to use constructor or super. https://www.reactnative.guide/6-conventions-and-code-style/6.4-es7-features.html

Comment: Perhaps, I haven't got a chance to learn about ES7 yet. still, I believe it answers OP's question

Comment: He is asking about difference between those two which is one is written on es6 and the other one in es7. Both of them are correct though. Please click on the link I have provided in my answer to read more about es7

Comment: Yeah, I just learned about it [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599), thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

Copied from reactJS website.

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t
>   need to implement a constructor for your React component.
>
> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
>   When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
>   should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs.
>
> Typically, in React constructors are only used for two purposes:
>
> ```
> Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
> Binding event handler methods to an instance.
> ```
>
> You should not call setState() in the constructor(). Instead, if your
>   component needs to use local state, assign the initial state to
>   this.state directly in the constructor:
>
> Constructor is the only place where you should assign this.state
>   directly. In all other methods, you need to use this.setState()
>   instead.
>
> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in the
>   constructor. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

And here is the purpose of super() ,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

I tried with babel, Here's what I get.

> With Constructor I get this function,

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
     this.state = {}
    }
}
```

Related part in ES5,

```
var App =
/*#__PURE__*/
function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(App, _React$Component);

  function App(props) {
    var _this;

    _classCallCheck(this, App);

    _this.state = {};
    return _possibleConstructorReturn(_this);
  }

  return App;
}(React.Component);
```

> Without Constructor

```
class App extends React.Component{
    state = {}
}
```

ES5 code

```
var App =
/*#__PURE__*/
function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(App, _React$Component);

  function App() {
    var _getPrototypeOf2;

    var _temp, _this;

    _classCallCheck(this, App);

    for (var _len = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
      args[_key] = arguments[_key];
    }

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(_this, (_temp = _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (_getPrototypeOf2 = _getPrototypeOf(App)).call.apply(_getPrototypeOf2, [this].concat(args))), _this.state = {}, _temp));
  }

  return App;
}(React.Component);
```

Comment: can you provide link to this

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it? What is the purpose of using constructor and super?

Constructors and the `super`-keyword are not react specific, but JavaScript specific. Search for inheritance and "OOP" in JavaScript to better understand it (e.g. [this medium article](https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/super-and-extends-in-javascript-es6-understanding-the-tough-parts-6120372d3420)). `super` and inheritance is also not only bound to JavaScript, many other languages also use it and explain it accordingly, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) for example is a good explanation of how the `super`-keyword should be used in java.

> Why do we pass props in constructor and super?

Check [Why Do We Write super(props)?](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/).

> Is React.Component and Component same?

Yes. In the head-section of the files are a bunch of `import ...`-statements. For `React.Component` you will find something like `import * as React from "react"` or `import React from "react"`. In case of `Component` you will find `import { Component } from "react"`. [Check the `import`-documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for more information.

> I am asking difference between 2 codes above and benefits of using each one?

There is no difference in the result. Both versions work the same and there is no (notable) difference in performance. One version is shorter and less noisy. If you have no further instructions in the constructor, I would recommend suppressing it.