# Why i can't get params from react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

https://github.com/Vladislav747/Electron_With_React

Try to get id from params here - https://github.com/Vladislav747/Electron_With_React/blob/master/src/components/Editing/index.js
line 17 - but got undefined - Where is mistake???

Answer (score 0):

You won't have access to this.props unless you don't initialise the constructor.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53022470/12855221.

Comment: It didn't help me(

Comment: Problem was with Router - I should use HashRouter from react-router in my case!